# Airflow: how to restart frozen task_instances updating the database

Tags: scheduler, freeze, airflow

I have an issue with airflow 1.8.2.
This issues perhaps has been already fixed in [AIRFLOW-1641](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1641) and perhaps is already available in airflow 1.9.0. However, I can't upgrade and need to know if there is someone which knows how to restart a task_istance using only SQL.  I know this is a bad practice.
My idea is to set the data in the database so that the scheduler will reload and reschedule the task instance again.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update the associated `dag_run` table records to and set the `state` column to "running" and then delete any associated `task_instance` records. Something like the following

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE  dag_run
   SET  state = 'running'
 WHERE  (dag_id, execution_date) IN ( SELECT  dag_id
                                           ,  execution_date
                                        FROM  task_instance
                                       WHERE  [... criteria for "frozen" ...]
                                    GROUP BY  dag_id
                                           ,  execution_date);

DELETE FROM  task_instance
      WHERE  [... criteria for "frozen" ...];

COMMIT;
```